# Regex not to match email id

Tags: javascript, regex

```
By Mel An, abf@abc.com
By Dem, abc.com / Abc 
By Sam, John, Todd, and John 
By Jer
```

I need a regex that matches not the `email id`. 
It should provide all the text, except the first one. i.e

```
By Mel An, 
By Dem, abc.com / Abc 
By Sam, John, Todd, and John 
By Jer
```

I want to use JavaScript regex only, I tried with `.*(?=,\s.*@.*com)` but the problem is it just matches the case which has `email id`. If `email id` exists, it should not capture `email id` and if `email id` doesn't exists it should match all text.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: (.*)(\b(, .*abc.com))

Comment: ^((?!.*@.*com).)*$

Answer (score 0):

Take each line as a string. Divide each string into substrings and then apply a match() method. The time complexity and space complexity will be greater for large input size but it will still work.

Comment: I want to use Javascript regex only, I tried with .*(?=,\s.*@.*com)   but the problem is it just matches the case which has email id. If email id exists, it should not capture email id and if it doesnt have it should match all text. Please help